# StackView constraint unintentionally affecting other elements

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistackview

I have two horizontal StackViews which both have two images inside.
The behaviour I'm trying to get is for the two StackViews to occupy the entire width on the iPhone 8, and shrink while switching to smaller devices while maintaining the aspect ratio (hence the constraint Width <= 150 and 1:1 Ratio).

For some reason, changing the StackView internal spacing OR changing the constraint width as show is unintentionally affecting other elements. I have a header image pinned to the top that is trailing the StackView. I do not want this behaviour. I want the StackViews to be independent from any other element on the screen.  I want the images to equally take up the widths of the screen on an iPhone 8, and shrink when switching to smaller devices.

Any one know what I can do?

https://gyazo.com/00776929b919ab0acc1b6dae3bb96e3f

Edit:
https://gyazo.com/11b10cbb52c3c06891a00ee778aba692

(Constraints on the top header image)

https://gyazo.com/cc0f7a06e766678914e7a5dc4596ffd3

(Constraints on the StackView)

https://gyazo.com/baa797530ed1d9f3cad320077767168a

(Constraints on the first image in the StackView)

Summary:

What I'm trying to do: Make the images in the StackView keep a 1:1 aspect ratio while scaling down automatically for devices < iPhone 8

What is happening: StackView trailing constraint is unintentionally affecting other views also using the trailing constraint

Comment: try using horizontal in container with proper width you want also make us show imgView constraints

Comment: As you said your header image is trailing to stack view that's what causing this behaviour, you should remove this constraint, and try adding  a trailing constraint to main view.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity of my question. Both are trailing to the superview. I don't really understand how trailing the StackView to the superview should affect everything else, but the StackView reclines, bringing the trailing with it.

Comment: I've updated my question with more images of the constraints.